# Cypress parallel run with Browserstack

Tags: cypress, browserstack, cypress-cucumber-preprocessor

I'm trying to run Cypress BDD test suites with Browserstack but i kept getting this error
CYPRESS_RUN_FAILEDCypress failed to run. Hide stack trace [-]
The plugins file is missing or invalid.

> Your `pluginsFile` is set to `.\cypress\plugins\index.js`, but either
> the file is missing, it contains a syntax error, or threw an error
> when required. The `pluginsFile` must be a `.js`, `.ts`, or `.coffee`
> file.
>
> Or you might have renamed the extension of your `pluginsFile`. If
> that's the case, restart the test runner.
>
> Please fix this, or set `pluginsFile` to `false` if a plugins file is
> not necessary for your project.
>
> Error: Cannot find module 'cypress-cucumber-preprocessor' Require
> stack:
>
> - .\cypress\plugins\index.js
> - \cypress_package\4.12.1\app\packages\server\lib\plugins\child\run_plugins.js
> - \cypress_package\4.12.1\app\packages\server\lib\plugins\child\index.js
>   at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:798:15)
>   at Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:691:27)
>   at Module._load (electron/js2c/asar.js:717:26)
>   at Function.Module._load (electron/js2c/asar.js:717:26)
>   at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:853:19)
>   at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
>   at Object. (.\cypress\plugins\index.js:2:18)
>   at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:968:30)
>   at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:986:10)
>   at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:816:32)
>   at Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:728:14)
>   at Module._load (electron/js2c/asar.js:717:26)
>   at Function.Module._load (electron/js2c/asar.js:717:26)
>   at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:853:19)
>   at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
>   at module.exports (\cypress_package\4.12.1\app\packages\server\lib\plugins\child\run_plugins.js:208:15)
>
> cypress run process exited with code 1 cypress run failed, exiting
> with code: 1

After following the answer suggestion, it seems it cannot read my stepDef and Page class files;
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KtF71.png)

Answer (score 0):

From the stack trace, I see:

`Cannot find module 'cypress-cucumber-preprocessor' Require stack`

Looks like you're missing the dependency.

Cypress execution on BrowserStack requires you to explicitly mention the npm packages required by the test in the `browserstack.json` file.

Here's the documentation link: https://www.browserstack.com/docs/automate/cypress/npm-packages

Comment: After following the answer suggestion, it seems it cannot read my stepDef and Page class files and it failed because of that. I've added the screenshot to the comment above.

Comment: @Bishop - Did you check if there's any change in `package_config_options` is required to set for the cucumber preprocessor?